# Grab DOM element after an external script has run

Tags: javascript, dom, next.js, dom-events

I have a Next.JS page that loads an external script. This external script modifies the DOM (Specifically places a div and an iframe on the page), it's a chat widget. The div that's added becomes the last child of the body, and I'm trying to grab it with `document.body.lastChild`. I'm running the logic in the onLoad property of Next's script component.
Problem is, the timing seems to be off. It's grabbing the last child before the div is added, verified by logging.

Not sure why... I've tried running the logic in window onload listener, document onload listener, within useEffect, etc. Any ideas? I'm trying to grab the div so I can position it differently, for context. It renders in the bottom right of the screen by default.

```
<Script
     id="scriptid"
     src="scriptsource"
     onLoad={() => {
       functionFromScript();
       // my logic to grab the newly added div from the above function
       document.onload = () => {
       console.log('All loaded')
       const chatDiv = document.body.lastChild;
       console.log(chatDiv)
       chatDiv.style.position = 'relative';
     };
    }}>
</Script>
```

Comment: If you have no control over the sites DOM/HTML/Script you may require timeouts to await the first element you require to be active. That's if waiting for window load does not properly give you what you want and the element may show up later say upon clicking a button?

Comment: @BGPHiJACK seems so hacky but I agree. I just am having a hard time accepting that theres not control over the DOM with next. I've done it many times with useEffect, but not while waiting for another external script to load.

Comment: If this is a case of you using two or more scripts on a site, you may globally scope functions and all sorts for the purpose of accessing mechanisms. window.functionFromScript = functionFromScript; Given this is your site, otherwise you may need to perform hacky stuff to get an "API" going for yourself.

Comment: Not sure if that would make a difference in me being able to grab the dom element in question, considering all the code in the onLoad of the script component is supposed to run after the script has loaded. I implemented a interval to keep checking for the div and it works

Comment: Maybe [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)